# Calulation on Angular View

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a cart using Angular, during process of that I faced a issue about calculation.

In my scenario I have code something like

```
<label>No. of item</label>
<div>{{totalItems}}</div> 


<div ng-repeat="cartElement in currentCartDetails.cartElements">
        <span>{{cartElement.productName}}</span>
        <span>{{cartElement.productCode}}</span>
        <span>{{cartElement.productPrice}}</span>
        <span>{{cartElement.quantity}}</span>
    </div>
```

What I want, add all something like

```
 totalItems += cartElement.quantity
```

I know there are so many option to display the value 
eg. using calculation from server side, iteration in calculation to controller

But what I am looking for, when I am iterate object on view page is there any way to calculate there and get benefit of tow way binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to do it with function?
Define a function inside your controller like **calculateTotal** then call it for every iteration.

```
$scope.totalItems = 0;
...
$scope.calculateTotal = function(cart){
  $scope.totalItems += cart.quantity;
}
...
```

then in your template

```
<div ng-repeat="cartElement in currentCartDetails.cartElements" ng-init="calculateTotal(cartElement)">
  <span>{{cartElement.productName}}</span>
  <span>{{cartElement.productCode}}</span>
  <span>{{cartElement.productPrice}}</span>
  <span>{{cartElement.quantity}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, to reduce one step of iteration in controller, I just forgot about this process.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by ,

Method 1:

HTML :

```
<div>{{gettotalItems(currentCartDetails.cartElements)}}</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.gettotalItems = function(cart_data){
  var num = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<cart_data.length;i++) {
      num += cart_data[0].quantity;
  }
  return num;
}
```

Method 2:

HTML:

```
<div ng-init="gettotalItems(currentCartDetails.cartElements)>{{totalItems}}</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.gettotalItems = function(cart_data){
      var num = 0;
      for(var i=0;i<cart_data.length;i++) {
          num += cart_data[0].quantity;
      }
      $scope.totalItems = num;
    }
```

Advantage is You can get the total cart value directly in one call by passing entire List of Objects. instead of, counting each time during iteration.